# Comparação de tabelas usando o título para junção com LIKE e CONCAT?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu estou criando uma pagina de troca de livros, fiz duas tabelas a de desejos e meus. até a parte do desejo do usuário logado achar os livros dos outros eu consegui fazer, mas gostaria tb quero q os outros usuários tenha como desejo os livros do usuário logado. tipo: eu ter um livro A e desejar um B e um outro usuário ter o B e desejar um A, e aparecer apenas resultados com essas condições.o campo de desejo poder ser titulo,autor e gênero. Meu select q fiz até agora:

```
   SELECT b.meu,b.autor, b.genero,b.userid, b.foto
      FROM desejos AS a 
      INNER JOIN meus AS b ON
        (CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', b.meu,'%')or
        CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', b.genero,'%')or
        CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', b.autor,'%'))
      WHERE
        a.userid = $_SESSION[id]
          AND
        b.userid != $_SESSION[id]
tentei colocar "and

   CONCAT('%', b.meu,'%') LIKE (CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') or  
   CONCAT('%', b.genero,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%')or
   CONCAT('%', b.autor,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%'))
```

mas n deu certo. as tabelas [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]